# why is the concatenation of an int and a string not complaining at compile time

Tags: c#

I have the following in visual studio, and its not complaining:

```
int? int1;
int? int2;

string str = int1 + "-" + int2;
```

my guess is this will throw an exception somewhere at runtime, but why is visual studio allowing this? Just because it could be null? Is a null int treated the same way as a null string?

Comment: If you phrase it like that it sounds like JavaScript...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of overloads to the `+` operator, two of them are:

```
operator + (string s, object o)
operator + (object o, string s)
```

The effect of this is that you can "add" an object of any type to a string.

The implementation of the overload will use `ToString` to get a string representation of that object and concat it with the string.  However, it will treat any null object (or strings) as if they're an empty string, and not throw an exception at runtime.

Note that, as a result of passing an `int?` to an `object` it will result in the value being boxed, because it's a struct, and there's special support for boxing `Nullable<T>` such that if `HasValue` is false (i.e. it logically represents a null value) it boxes `null` rather than boxing a `Nullable` that represents null.

Comment: @GrantWinney It would, but the implementation of the operator specifically checks for null first, and treats null values as if they were an empty string, as I said in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the in-depth explanation, makes sense now

Comment: @GrantWinney Note that `((int?)null).ToString() == string.Empty`, because `Nullable<>` is built that way. http://ideone.com/HvuQ1s

Comment: @xanatos Also note that, while that's completely true, the last paragraph of my answer explains why `ToString` won't actually be called on a `Nullable` instance in the code from the question.  The boxing results in `null` being boxed, not a `Nullable<int?>`.

Comment: *So assuming int1 is null* Note that `Nullable<>` is a sleight of hand. There is no `null` that is saved anywhere, unless you box it in an `object`. `Nullable<>` is a struct, defined like `public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct { public bool HasValue { get { } }, public T Value { get {} set { } } }`, so a flag indicating if `Value` is to be shown or not, and a `Value` that is "hidden" if `HasValue == false`

Answer (score 5):

The `+` operator here is concatenation, not addition.

Secondly, the `+` operator is overloaded for `Nullable<T>` in a way that doesn't cause `NullReferenceException`s.

However your code won't compile because you haven't set `int1` and `int2` to a value. However if you use `null`, then the code the `string` result will be just "`-`".

Here is a CodingGround project with your code and it outputs just "`-`": http://goo.gl/sHMqk4

Comment: In this particular case the overload of the `+` operator called will not involve the `Nullable` type.  If he were passing two `int?` values (or one and an `int`) then it would.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, I changed the title from addition to concatenation

Comment: *Secondly, the + operator is overloaded for Nullable<T> in a way that doesn't cause NullReferenceExceptions.* In C#, `string` addition works perfectly well with `null` values. They are converted to `""`

Comment: From the C# Language Spec: *These overloads of the binary + operator perform string concatenation. **If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is substituted**

Comment: @xanatos I sounds to me like the section you're quoting of Dai's answer is about how all + operators on value types are lifted to support nullable versions of those types, which is correct, but also irrelevant to the point at hand as no such overloads are used.